# How to pass more than one variable in .bat file using VBS

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have a vbs code like:

```
Message4 = "Please enter Check Out Path"           
 Title4 = "Check Out Path "
 variable1 = InputBox(Message4, Title4,"", 4500, 4500)

 Message5 = "Please enter SVN URL"           
 Title5 = "SVN URL "
 variable2 = InputBox(Message5, Title5, "", 4500, 4500)

 Folder\batchfile.bat"""
 objWshell.Run "batxhfile.bat"
```

and also batch file named `batchfile.bat`

```
@echo off

Color 42
 echo. [ SVN Updater ]

set Checkout_path=checkout path
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
set svn_url=SVN path

 echo. Updating %Checkout_path% to SVN...
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:checkout /url:"%svn_url%" /path:"%Checkout_path%" /closeonend:2
 echo. done.
 echo.
echo. Operation complete.
```

Now i want to pass the value of `variable1` and `variable2` from vbs code to batch file in the place of `checkout path` and `svn path` i have tried lots of method but no success uptill plz help.

Comment: Is you batch script calling VBS, or is VBS calling batch? Why a hybrid solution? Why not do everything in batch or everything in VBS?

Answer (score 0):

I agree why you wouldn't simply call 'TortoiseProc.exe' from a VBS, however you may have you reasons for calling via a batch script. Simply pass arguments into a batch from a VBS:

```
`Const ERR_SUCCESS = 0
Const BAT_SCRIPT = "<folder>\batchfile.bat"
Dim oWSH, sCmd, iRC, sVar1, sVar2
Set oWSH = WScipt.CreateObjects("WScript.Shell")
Do While sVar1 <> ""
  sVar1 = InputBox("Please enter Check Out Path", "Check Out Path", 4500, 4500)
Loop
Do While sVar2 <> ""
  sVar2 = InputBox("Please enter SVN URL", "SVN URL", 4500, 4500)
Loop  
sCmd = "cmd.exe /c """ & BAT_SCRIPT & "" "" & sVar1 & "" "" & sVar2 & """" 
WScript.Echo "COMMAND: sCmd"
On Error Resume Next
iRC = oWSH.Run(sCmd, 0, True)
If iRC <> ERR_SUCCESS And Err.Number <> ERR_SUCCESS Then 
  MsgBox "ERROR: [" & Err.Source & "] " & CStr(Err.Number) & " - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
         "       '" & BAT_SCRIPT "' return code = '" & CStr(iRC) & "' from command:" & vbCrLf & _
         "       COMMAND:  " & sCmd, vbOkOnly, "Batch Script Error"
End If
Err.Clear
Set oWSH = Nothing`
```

You're result batch script command should be called like the following:
 
    `cmd.exe /c "<folder>\batchfile.bat" "<var1>" "<var2>"`

Ensure your batch script gathers arguments, removes string double quotes and validates correctly:

```
`set Checkout_path=%1
set Checkout_path=%Checkout_path:~1,-1%
set svn_url=%2
set svn_url=%svn_url:~1,-1%
if /i "%Checkout_path%" ne "" (
  exit /b 99
)
if /i "%svn_url%" ne "" (
  exit /b 99
)`
```

Hope this helps ;)